# How to use MATLAB buildin functions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I want to apply 2D-DCT on the array of data collected from image pixels.

tried [Accord.Math](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_CosineTransform_DCT.htm) which is too slow to work with and also values vary from 50 to 100 as compared to matlab generated values which i think does not sounds good because i also have to apply LSB to these values.

MATLAB was applying DCT pretty fast so i want to use its dct2() method..

I have read some posts but mostly are about deploying m file as dll in C#..now the problem is dct2() depends on dct() which in turn depends in FFT()..and other checking functions too..

Now what should i use??? Deployment looks better option but how to include all dependencies??

and if any other suggestion please a little help or links so i can implement easily..actually I'm new in C# and also languages interfacing thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use

deploytool and create an external library for your .m files ans use this in C#, I have linux so I do not have dotnet available, I have for java and C/C++ ,also you can investigate mcc, that compiles matlab code to create a dll like [here](http://www.labviewpro.net/upfiles/dllmatlablabview.pdf) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Urda.png)